# VBA disabling drag and drop prevents users to copy and paste to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to disable drag and drop on a specific Excel workbook.
I wrote the following code on VBA editor on 'My Workbook' section.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
End Sub
```

Problem is: after that people cannot copy-paste any cell from this workbook to another.
How's so?

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: @BigBen hi thank you for your answer. How can I prevent people to use drag and drop but allow them to copy and paste?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, It disables only the drag and drop for me but still allows regular copy and pasting within the workbook and across workbooks. Since it is a change at the application level no workbooks in that application instance can drag and drop however.